# Short Story: Time Anomalies that are Increasing

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story I read in the late seventies/early eighties, probably in an anthology book. The story is about someone investigating time anomalies that seem to be increasing. I remember some of the examples:

1. An unknown, older dog shows up at the door, seems thrilled to see the resident, but the resident turns him away. Years later, the resident raises a dog from puppyhood to adult, and one day the dog disappears. He realizes that the dogs were the same animal. The old dog having shown up before he had even been born and he turned it away.
2. A man's marriage is on the rocks because the wife developed film from their vacation and one of the pictures shows an older version of the son, and the father, but with a different woman unknown to them all. The implication being that the picture is from the future where the wife has been replaced.
3. A man appears suddenly in the middle of the street and is killed by a car. His clothes and items in his pockets are all decades old, including coinage and receipts. The driver who struck him said he appeared out of nowhere. Mention, I think, is made of so many stories of husbands going for cigarettes and never being seen again.

Comment: Is this just one short story, or a set of short stories? The first one sounds familiar... I thought it was in another question.

Comment: It's a single story. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this ***[I'm Scared](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41297)*** by Jack Finney...? It was first published in the [September 1951 edition](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?272285) of *Collier's*.

As per the The Internet Speculative Fiction Database synopsis:

> A retired man investigate odd occurrences in central New York, believing there is a large-scale conspiracy at work.

An excerpt relating to the anomaly involving the dog:

> Miss Eisenberg hunted for her dog for many days afterward, inquired of neighbors, put ads in the papers, but she never found him. "Then one night I was getting ready for bed; I happened to glance out the front window down at the street, and suddenly I remembered something I'd forgotten all about. I remembered the dog I'd chased away over two years before." Miss Eisenberg looked at me for a moment, then she said flatly, "It was the same dog. If you own a dog you know him, you can't be mistaken, and I tell you it was the same dog. Whether it makes sense or not, my dog was lost—I chased him away—two years before he was born."

An excerpt relating to the anomaly involving the photograph of a man with his wife and son:

> For an instant it seemed to me like merely one more photograph in the group; then I saw the difference. Mr. Kerch looked much the same, bareheaded and grinning broadly, but he wore an entirely different suit. The boy, standing beside him, wore long pants, and a good three inches taller, obviously older, but equally obviously the same boy. The woman was an entirely different person. Dressed smartly, her light hair catching the sun, she was very pretty and attractive. She was smiling into the camera and holding Mr. Kerch's hand.
> I looked up at him. "Who is this?"
> Wearily, Mr. Kerch shook his head. "I don't know," he said suddenly, then exploded: "I don't know! I've never seen her in my life!" He turned to look at his wife, but she would not return his glance, and he turned back to me, shrugging.

An excerpt relating to the anomaly involving the car accident victim found with seventy-five-year-old coins in his pockets:

> Captain Rihm turned on the bench to see if he'd caught my interest, then continued. "There was about a dollar in change in the dead guy's pocket, and one of the boys picked up a nickel and showed it to me. Now you've seen plenty of nickels, the new ones with Jef-ferson's picture, the buffalo nickels they made before that, and once in a while you still even see the old Liberty-head nickels; they quit making them before the first world war. But this one was even older than that. It had a shield on the front, a United States shield, and a big five on the back; I used to see that kind when I was a boy. And the funny thing was, that old nickel looked new; what coin dealers call 'mint condition,' like it was made the day before yesterday. The date on that nickel was 1876, and there wasn't a coin in his pocket dated any later."

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Comment: Was there a bit in that story where something strange happened with paint on the side of a house or is that a different story.  Like a strip of paint suddenly appearing on the house and then disappearing,

Comment: @EmsleyWyatt That's the same story.